# How to make my div count as a background slider and dont make big horizontal scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my problem is this:

I am having a div which is 1500px, and div is making a horizontal scroll bar. Well as you can see my header size is 960px. How can i apply things to have that div like a background, i mean when i open up the page to don't have scrolling bar (like when my page is 960px, and div is on it,too).

Div code is this:

```
<div id="amazingslider-wrapper-1" style="display:block;position:static;width:1047px;margin:0px auto 0px;">
  <div id="amazingslider-1" style="display:block;position:static;margin:0 auto;">
    <ul class="amazingslider-slides" style="display:none;">
      <li>
        <img src="images/SrbimationProlece.png" alt="Prolece na Srbimationu!" data-description="Ne propustite ni jedan sou!" />
        <a href="http://www.google.com/"><button class="as-btn-white-large">Saznaj vise!</button></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/Pozadina.png" alt="Pozadina" />
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="amazingslider-thumbnails" style="display:none;">
      <li>
        <img src="images/SrbimationProlece-tn.png" alt="Prolece na Srbimationu!" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/Pozadina-tn.png" alt="Pozadina" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now it is 1047px but when i put it to 1.5k or 2k it makes a big scroll bar.
Div is a slider made in jquery.

It should be something like this http://www.funimation.com that (slider at background of the page)

The slider code is working perfect that isn't the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `overflow:hidden;` ?

Comment: cant access your link

Comment: "overflow:hidden" How do you mean it Ted?. By the way, how do you think u cant access that site? It isnt mine. Before u go inside it there is a short capcha u need to write it.

Comment: @Ted Well hidden wont help me because i cant hide the picture its showing. Pictures need to be shown on slider not hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your post's comments I think you're confusing `display: none` with `overflow: hidden`. `overflow: hidden` will hide whatever overflows outside your container div while `display: none` will hide the div and its contents entirely.

```
#amazingslider-wrapper-1 {
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

This is shorthand for setting `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` to hidden.